# dynamic class name in grails controller

Tags: grails

i want to use post params to access domain in controller for Create , Update or Delete instance
like this example

```
    def getForm(String name){
       // name = "User"
       def className = "com."+name
       def nameInstance = new className(params) //nameInstance = userInstance , className = com.User
       [nameInstance :nameInstance]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject grailsApplication into your Controller then you can create an instance of the class with the following :

```
def clazz = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(className).clazz
def nameInstance = clazz.newInstance(params)
```

Comment: thank @Dave but didn't work for create new data, it's work for findAll,get,list

Comment: You can't use `new` with a variable, but you can use it to call static methods. Use `clazz.newInstance(params)` to invoke the constructor.